# Can already opened event log screens of powershell on windows event viewer can be hacked offline by hackers?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, hacking, safety

Can Windows powershell give me fake or altered outputs if I use common commands primarily used in powershell checking hash codes is option but they can be altered too theorically so its not that trustable as seen

If I disconnect from the internet and while the powershell eventid logs of event properties were open can they be edited and changed by hackers even renewing the event id history page in milisecconds to check their validity but without using event monitors because they can also be hacked in my system same theorically

I won’t open new operate system I primarily need of verification of cleanness on my recent session.

I want 100% guarantee or close to that rate if you can help me I would glad

As I mentioned above its critical for me

Answer (score 1):

Once a system has been successfully and completely compromised you can’t even trust the time it displays let alone anything of real importance that it shows you.

At least: that is the theory.